# Prove that $C = \{x \in X: (f_n(x)) \text{ converges} \}$ is a closed set in $X$

Tags: general-topology, functions, metric-spaces, continuity

The question goes like:
Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let ${f_n}$ be an equicontinuous sequence in $C(X)$. Show that $C = \{x \in X: (f_n(x))  \text{ converges} \}$ is a closed set in $X$

My attempt was to construct $x_k \rightarrow x$, and show that $x$ is also in the set. So from compactness and continuity, we can say that every $f_n$ is bounded, so that every sequence $f_n(x)$ is also bounded. Thus we can use three step approximation 
$|f_n(x)-f_m(x)| \leq |f_n(x)-f_n(x_k)|+|f_n(x_k)-f_m(x_k)|+|f_m(x_k)-f_m(x)|$
I don't know if it is right? Do we need to use compactness to discretize the space?

Also, can we draw $f_n$ is uniformly bounded from compactness of $X$ and equicontinuity?

Comment: For your final question: Let $f_n(x)=n$. Then $f_n$ are equicontinuous but not uniformly bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is essentially correct, but needs no compactness of the domain, just that it is metric. In more detail:

Suppose $(x_k)$ is a sequence from $C$ such that $x_k \rightarrow x$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$. So let $\varepsilon>0$. Apply equicontinuity for $\frac{\varepsilon}{3}$, so that we have $\delta > 0$ such that

$$\forall_{p,q \in [0,1]} |p - q| < \delta \rightarrow \forall_n |f_n(p) - f_n(q)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$

There also exists $K$ such that $k \ge K$ implies $|x_k - x| < \delta$.

The sequence $(f_n(x_K))$ is convergent, as $x_K$ is in $C$. So there exists $N$ such that $n,m \ge N$ implies $|f_n(x_K) - f_m(x_K)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ (as all convergent sequences are Cauchy).

Now apply

$$|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \le |f_n(x) - f_n(x_K)| + |f_n(x_K) + f_m(x_K)| + |f_m(x_K) - f_m(x)|$$

(as you suggested) and see that for $n,m \ge N$ we indeed have that $|f_n(x) - f_m(x)| < \varepsilon$. The first and last term follow from the equicontinuity condition and $|x_K - x| < \delta$, and the middle term is from Cauchyness of $(f_n(x_K))$ from before.

Conclusion: if a sequence from $C$ converges to $x$, then $(f_n(x))$ is Cauchy and hence convergent (as the reals are complete). So $x \in C$ and the proof is complete. No compactness or boundedness of sequences are used in the proof.